# Node knex Bookshelf - using dynamic where clause with fetch

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I need to modify an existing query, which fetches model instances with related items, to dynamically change the `where` clause depending if a search term is provided or an ID is provided.

If I modify the original below from:

```
return db.model('Users').where('id', userId)
      .fetch({withRelated: [
        'userNames.userMessages',
        {
          ...
        },
      ]}).then(function(user) {
```

To this, I get error **db.model(...).fetch is not a function**

```
    var query = db.model('Users')
      .fetch({withRelated: [
        'userNames.userMessages',
        {
          ...
        },
      ]});

    if (userId) {
      query.where('id', userId);
    } else if (searchTerm) {
      query.where('name', 'like', '%' + searchTerm + '%');
    }

    query.then(function(user) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch()` requires a [model instance](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetch), created by `new`, `forge()` or a result of some other query. `db.model('Users')` alone is just like a "class", having only the [Model static methods](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-subsection-static) available.

So one possible solution for your dynamic query could be:

```
var query = db.model('Users')
  .collection()
  .query(function(qb) {
    if (userId) {
      qb.where('id', userId);
    } else if (searchTerm) {
      qb.where('name', 'like', '%' + searchTerm + '%');
    }
  })
  .fetch({withRelated: [
    'userNames.userMessages',
    {
      ...
    },
  ]});

query.then(function(user) {
```